# React Native loading new copy of image into memory on entering background in iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native

I've created a fresh React Native project (v0.60.4) and I'm running it on a real iPhone 11 Pro iOS 13.1.3 in release mode. The app.js is super simple:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Image source={require('./test.png')} />
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I've noticed that every time my app enters the background (when I switch to another app), I see a jump in memory usage that's never freed (even with memory warnings).

[image]

I can see that the increase is caused by a new ImageIO_PNG_Data, created as the app moves into the background.

While this image is relatively modest in size, in my real app it's causing app crashes after the user app switches a lot.

Here's the same app, same image, written in Swift, using the same method to create a UIImage that RN is using.

[image]

No extra images loaded into memory. What is RN doing differently that's loading these extra images into memory and not clearing the old ones? What's happening when the app enters the background?

**Update**

After marking a generation I noticed that all of the large images were coming from what looks like iOS's snapshot of the app as it entered the background:

```
   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mmap
   1 ImageIO _ImageIO_Malloc
   2 ImageIO AppleJPEGReadPlugin::copyImageBlockSet(InfoRec*, CGImageProvider*, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const*)
   3 ImageIO IIO_Reader::CopyImageBlockSetProc(void*, CGImageProvider*, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const*)
   4 ImageIO IIOImageProviderInfo::CopyImageBlockSetWithOptions(void*, CGImageProvider*, CGRect, CGSize, __CFDictionary const*)
   5 CoreGraphics CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions
   6 QuartzCore CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double, double)
   7 QuartzCore CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
   8 QuartzCore CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*)
   9 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double)
  10 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
  11 UIKitCore __83-[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]_block_invoke_4
  12 UIKitCore -[UIApplication _performWithUICACommitStateSnapshotting:]
  13 UIKitCore __83-[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]_block_invoke_2
  14 UIKitCore +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
  15 UIKitCore __83-[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]_block_invoke
  16 UIKitCore -[UIScene _applyOverrideSettings:forActions:]
  17 UIKitCore -[UIWindowScene _applySnapshotSettings:forActions:]
  18 UIKitCore -[UIApplication _createSnapshotContextForScene:withName:performLayoutWithSettings:]
  19 UIKitCore __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke_3
  20 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
  21 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction _executeNextRequest]
  22 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSceneSnapshotAction executeRequestsWithHandler:completionHandler:expirationHandler:]
  23 UIKitCore __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke_2
  24 UIKitCore -[UIApplication _beginSnapshotSessionForScene:withSnapshotBlock:]
  25 UIKitCore __65-[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]_block_invoke
  26 UIKitCore -[UIScene _enableOverrideSettingsForActions:]
  27 UIKitCore -[UIScene _performSystemSnapshotWithActions:]
  28 UIKitCore -[UIApplication _performSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]
  29 UIKitCore __98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_3
  30 UIKitCore __98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke.30
  31 UIKitCore -[UIApplication prepareSnapshotsWithAction:forScene:completion:]
  32 UIKitCore __98-[_UISceneSnapshotBSActionsHandler _respondToActions:forFBSScene:inUIScene:fromTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_2
  33 UIKitCore -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]
  34 UIKitCore -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
  35 UIKitCore -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:]
  36 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
  37 FrontBoardServices __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2
  38 FrontBoardServices -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]
  39 FrontBoardServices __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
  40 libdispatch.dylib 0x102a9b2a7
  41 libdispatch.dylib 0x102a9e9cf
  42 FrontBoardServices __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
  43 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible]
  44 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
  45 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
  46 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSource0
  47 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0
  48 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
  49 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
  50 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
  51 UIKitCore UIApplicationMain
  52 tmp main /...
  53 libdyld.dylib start
```

Comment: Try declaring `const IMAGE = require('./test.png')` outside the component, and then use by `<Image source={IMAGE} />` maybe multiple re-renders cause a memory leak.

Comment: Just tried, I still see the same behavior.

Comment: oh well worth a shot, maybe try removing the safe view wrapper too

Comment: No luck without SafeAreaView either I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Ah of course when the app enters the background the OS actually takes a picture of the application which is used a preview when scrolling through background applications. In our app we do something like this:

```
- (void)deleteAllTemporaryFiles
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"[Delegate] Deleting all temp files...");
  [self deleteDirectoryFiles:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
  [self deleteDirectoryFiles:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0]];
  [self deleteDirectoryFiles:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0]];
}

- (void)deleteDirectoryFiles:(NSString *)directory
{
  NSArray<NSString *> *temp = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:NULL];
  for (NSString *path in temp) {
    if (/* check for directories you want to keep here */) continue;
    @try {
      NSString *filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
      RCTLogInfo(@"[Delegate] Deleting %@",filePath);
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
      RCTLogInfo(@"[Delegate] Deletion error: %@", e);
    }
  }
}
```

And in the delegate:

```
// Delete all temp files when app is paused
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [self deleteAllTemporaryFiles];
}
```